# What exactly PowerShell extension is doing in Visual Studio Code when arrows rotating in the circle?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Can you help me figure out what exactly PowerShell is doing when two arrows keep rotating in the status line of Visual Studio Code ?

[image]

Comment: That's the universal symbol for "I'm busy" or "I'm doing something."  What it's actually doing is anyone's guess.

Comment: I assume it has something to do with intellisense for the PS addon - it checks all your code syntax on the fly and if modules need loading etc it does all that in the background. It also checks for updates regularly.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @RobertHarvey and @Scepticalist comments, it is the universal symbol for "I'm doing something", usually in the background.

As to what it is doing? Well, there is a few things that it could be doing. I have found that if you are using an extension like the [Microsoft PowerShell](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) for Visual Studio Code extension, there are in general two main things that could take up processing.

Intellisense is one intensive process, but after everything has been loaded, it is usually pretty efficient. Any slowness/performance issues would be seen in slow Intellisense suggestions, and usually wouldn't show up in the progress spinner... So what else?

The one process that I personally found to be the most intensive is the [PSScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer). There were cases where with large modules to took [several seconds to process](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1189). And even a case where simply having the [AzureRM module installed increased the analysis time from 3 to 34 minutes](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/841#issuecomment-388040175). That would definitely be a situation that could cause the spinner to run almost "continuously".

You can test if this is the case by disabling the `powershell.scriptAnalysis.enable` setting in the extension.